# Editing background of a template on the story board during an event trigger turns background black

Tags: expression-blend, blend

So, I am having an odd behavior.  Maybe it's intentional, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I haven't worked much in Blend and prior to this been mostly coding XAML manually.  I am trying create a custom template for a `MenuItem` and when it's being moused over, I need to turn its background a specific color.  So, I'm doing this `MouseEnter` event trigger on the `OuterBorder`.  When I try to change the color, no matter what color I set it as, it turns black immediately.  This happens on all of the control in template, regardless which one I choose.  So, I have to manually go into XAML and change it to the specific color.

After I set it to a specific color within the XAML code, if I try to change it through the Properties menu, it'll turn back to that color I set in the code.

If I export template into a `ResourceDictionary`, it lets me edit everything as if nothing wrong is occurring, but when the template is applied, the default background of the `MenuItem` control turns black.

By the way, this is Blend for Visual Studio 2013.

Any ideas what's going on?

What I ended up doing was not creating a separate even trigger and instead edited the template's existent triggers.  Which worked great.  My only concern is that the default one did not do fill, so I fail to see how there was a conflict between the two.  Not sure if anyone knows?

Comment: Just a tip, toggling Visibility for something like that instead of Opacity is a performance consideration even mentioned in various [performance tip docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189071(v=vs.95).aspx#use_visibility) for better practices moving forward. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Silly me.  I was trying to change background that didn't exist.  So, it had to create the background for the storyboard, and thus was setting it as the default black.  What I did was create a background and set it's opacity to 0% and then change that instead.  Worked as intended.